# Binding fails for new SOAP request in existing project

Tags: grails, soap, binding, wsdl, cxf

I've added a new SOAP request to an existing project that already uses a lot of SOAP requests. They all work fine. I add my new one in exactly the same way (code generated from WSDL through Apache CXF), yet somehow it fails.

I get this error:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not find wsdl:binding operation info for web method foo.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:113)
    at $Proxy51.foo(Unknown Source)
```

This is a Grails project, and the code is called like this:

```
FooRequest request = new FooRequest()
processResponse(order) { getPort().foo(request) }
```

It's the getPort().foo() at the bottom that apparently fails. <strike>In fact, I believe it's not the call that fails, but the creation of the closure, since processResponse() doesn't seem to get executed (I put a println on the first line of that method).</strike> **Edit:** It's the *execution* of the closure that fails, not the creation. So it really cannot find getPort().foo(), despite the fact that my generated interface does have this method:

```
public com.myproject.webservice.FooResponse foo(
    @WebParam(name = "in", targetNamespace = "")
    com.myproject.FooRequest in
);
```

getPort() returns a org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy@41079622, which it also does for other SOAP requests (the ones that work).

I cannot find any meaningful difference between my new code and the existing code. Any ideas what could be wrong? Any suggestions on where to look?

Edit: port.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique() does include my new foo() method. Yet when I call it, I get this weird wsdl:binding error, and the method doesn't get executed (it doesn't reach the println on the first line).

Edit: anonymized some stuff I intended to anonymize.

Comment: are you using the cxf plugin?  The proxy is not find the correct method in the class it is loading in the classpath.

Comment: I'm not using any Grails CXF plugin. I'm using the Apache CXF command line tools, and paste the generated code into the project. As far as I can tell, this has always worked in the past. I'm using Apache CXF 1.2.1, because that's the version that was used in the past.

Comment: port.metaClass.methods*.name.sort().unique() does include my new foo() method. So the method is in the class hierarchy, yet when it gets called, I get this weird wsdl:binding error, instead of the actual method being executed.

Comment: I am bit confused. I am not king on Groovy, but what is the signature of `getPort()`, what is returns? It should return the interface, what is it? And how `foo()` is related to `simSwitch()`?

Comment: `foo()` actually _is_ `simswitch`. I thought I'd anonymized it everywhere, but apparently I hadn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The JaxWsClientProxy may have a foo() method, but that's not my foo() method. It's a proxy for my foo() method that first checks whether this method actually exists in the WSDL on the remote server. And if I haven't updated the WSDL on the remote server with the foo request, then it throws the exception instead of calling my actual foo() method. I didn't expect this kind of check in the middle of what seemed like a regular method call, but apparently that check is the entire point of having such a WSDL/SOAP binding framework.

Connecting to a server that has the updated WSDL fixed the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This was happening to me in jboss EAP, the problem was that in module.xml of my framework there was not the dependency for jboss-cxf added, and as default it uses de jaxws spec. To solve this I added the following:

```
<module name="org.jboss.ws.cxf.jbossws-cxf-client" export="true"/>
```

export=true says that includes all the required libs for cxf library.

I hope this can help more people. I spent nearly a week on this.

Comment: I spent a week to fix this issue, and i found a few similar questions which had the same problem, but no solution. Due to your answer, i also found some information in the jboss-docs: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JBoss+Modules+and+WS+applications

Comment: Thanks, I hope it helps to others!.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a parameter name "in" ?

**in** is a reserved word in groovy. I suspect that is the problem.

Try renaming your parameter.